# How to determine value of statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, logic

Given statement $v(x): |x| = 2 \text{ where } x \in A = \{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. What will value of $\lnot v(x)$ look like?

Comment: Consider $|x| \ne 2$.

Comment: @hardmath, yes $v$ has domain $A$, I just thought, that this is correct notation for that.

Comment: I made a change to clarify your meaning.  Please review and roll back edit if not in keeping with your intention.

Comment: @hardmath it was. Thanks for clarifying!